# Pydev Django project compilation

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I installed pydev and eclipse to compile a django project. Everything looks good but one thing makes me crazy. When i change something in the code, i click to save it and hope to see the effect of changes. However, I cannot see the effect of what i change unless I terminate the program and re-run as as shown below. It is such a pain...

[image]

I used to use Pycharm, but it expired. In Pycharm, when the program runs once, i do not need to run it again and again. I can easily see the effect of my changes on the code by clicking save button. Is it possible to see the same thing in pydev and eclipse? Do you guys also see this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug Django with the autoreload feature, the Remote Debugger must be used and a patch must be applied to your code (just before the `if _name_ == "_main_"`: in your manage.py module):

```
import pydevd
pydevd.patch_django_autoreload(
  patch_remote_debugger=True, #Connect to the remote debugger.
  patch_show_console=True
)
```

So, doing that, starting the remote debugger and making a regular run should enable all the regular breakpoints that are put inside Eclipse to work in the Django process with the Remote Debugger (and the --noreload that PyDev added automatically to the launch configuration must be removed).

I have plans on improving that so that the debugger will automatically add tracing to spawned processes (probably for the next release), but on PyDev 3.3.3 this still requires doing this manual patch and using the remote debugger.

---

The above is related to a debug run. Now, on to the regular run...

When you do a run as > pydev: django, it should create a run configuration (which you can access at run > run configuration). Then, open that run configuration > arguments and remove the '--noreload' (leaving only the 'runserver' argument).

Then, you can simply rerun it with Ctrl+F11 (if you've set it to launch the previously launched application as indicated in http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html) 
-- (Or alternatively you can run it with: Alt + R, T, 1).

The only problem is that if you kill the process inside Eclipse it's possible that it leaves zombie processes around, so, you can use the pydevd.patch_django_autoreload(patch_show_console=True) as indicated above to open a console each time it spawns a new process (you can do a pydevd|<- ctrl space here to add an import to pydevd).

Note that this should work. If it's not working, make sure you don't have zombie processes around from a previous session (in windows you can do: taskkill /F /IM python.exe to make sure all Python processes are killed).

Another note (for when you don't actually have automatic reload): Ctrl+Shift+F9 will kill the currently running process and re-run it.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this for "import pydev" Unresolved import: pydevd
Unused import: pydevd
pydevd Found at: manage
import pydevd

Comment: Is this for only debugging? I do not want to debug, i just want to keep running the program and see the effect when i change some thing in the code.

Comment: Yes, the pydevd is needed for debugging. The main issue there is that PyDev will add a '--noreload' in the configuration, so, you can just remove that and it'll already work with multiple processes (although it had a problem where you killed the main process and it left child processes alive, not sure if it was fixed, so, you may still want to apply the patch just to show spawned consoles). For adding the pydev import, you can do 'pydev' and request a code completion (which adds the settrace too, but you can remove that...)

Comment: Note: the --noreload can be taken off at run > run configurations.

Comment: I took it off, but did not fix that issue.